# Android: ListView disappears in landscape view

Tags: android, landscape

I'm basically trying to create a listview of items underneath of a button that's on the top of my screen.  I currently have my listview overwritten with 4 textviews and it all works great until I make the app landscape.  This all works as long as it's portrait.

Here is my main activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Pull Pipeline Grid"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></ListView>
```

Here is my row.xml which is my listview override xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textSize="16sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="World"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

This could be a very simple fix, but i'm new to android development and I dont understand the piece i'm missing.    Here's the outcome i want

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
change orientation of LinearLayout to vertical like this

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Pull Pipeline Grid"
android:onClick="onClick"/>

   <ListView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
></ListView>
```

Hope it helps. Refer here for more ListView Samples http://coderzpassion.com/android-listview-with-image-and-text/